# Error when trying to define matrix

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I'm trying to define a matrix:

```
\begin{matrix}  
a & b & c \\
d & e & f
\end{matrix}
```

But I'm keep getting this error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.<inserted text>$ \begin{matrix}
! Missing $ inserted.<inserted text>$ \end{matrix}
```

Comment: `$\begin{matrix}...\end{matrix}$` should do!

Answer (score 2):

The `matrix` environment must be used in math mode, i.e. use `$\begin{matrix}...\end{matrix}$` or within one of the various math-environments such as `equation` or `align` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}% Only needed for `pmatrix` etc. 

\begin{document}

$
\begin{matrix}  
a & b & c \\ 
d & e & f
\end{matrix}$  

$\begin{pmatrix}  
a & b & c \\
d & e & f
\end{pmatrix}$


\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}  
a & b & c \\
d & e & f
\end{bmatrix} &\neq 
\begin{Bmatrix}  
a & b & c \\
d & e & f
\end{Bmatrix}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

[image]